# Run AngularJS directive on demand

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

I'm attempting to run a directive after some event, for instance, some click or a model change. Here is how my directive looks:

```
  .directive('enclose', function ($window, $http) {
      return function (scope, elm, attrs) {
          if (scope.$last) {
              var url = getCurrentPath($window);
              var rowid = scope.row.entity.id;
              $http.get(url + '/' + rowid + '/attachment').success(function (data) {
                  (data.length > 30) ? $(elm).removeAttr('disabled') : $(elm).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              })
          }
  };
```

Long story short: directive checks if a row has a file attached; if so, it enables download button.

In that table, where data is displayed, has a lot of rows, and it has pagination controls. So, issue raises when I click on next page (f.e.), all data displayed in the table is updated, but directive doesn't. I mean, directive does not run again, updating enable/disable attributes for each button.

I have two approachs: One, in my controller I have a scope variable, **currentPage**, and after it is updated, I call in some way to the directive. By the way, I'm using *Angular UI-grid* to render data.

```
  $scope.regulationGrid = {
          // ...
          onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
              $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
              $scope.currentPage = $scope.gridApi.pagination.getPage();
              $scope.gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function () {
                  $scope.currentPage = $scope.gridApi.pagination.getPage();
                  // Here should be the directive call
              });
          }
      };
```

Two, use a *$watch* function in the directive, who will be listen any changes in *$scope*.**currentPage** variable. But I didn't achieve to make it work, *directives* only run on load.

Is there any way to run **on demand** a directive? Because my directive is working on load, but no when *scope* changes.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

[image]
This is how looks the problem. Left table is right: rows 3rd, 4th & 8th have files enclosed so, it enables download button.
But Right table renders wrong this button because *directive* is no longer running. Its right values are rows 12th, 14th enabled.

So the point is, how can I check this values after I click on nextPage button?

Comment: try using directive as class or attribute and then add class or attribute on the fly...

Comment: Directives can't be 'called'. They are a static part of your website. If you want to conditionally display a directive, use `ng-show`/`ng-hide`. If you want to conditionally add or remove a directive from the DOM, use `ng-if`/`ng-switch`. I think you're going about your problem the wrong way - directives shouldn't be making `$http` calls in their link function.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, directives:

- Are not functions
- Cannot be called
- Are static parts of your website, unless you use `ng-if` or `ng-switch`
- Should not perform any business logic

It appears your problem is an XY problem, so let's start over. What are you trying to do?

From the looks of it, you want to set a directive as disabled or enabled based on the result of a HTTP call. Instead of performing the HTTP call inside of your directive, how about you pass the directive a variable from an isolation scope and alter that variable from a parent controller? This makes your code less coupled and lets you adhere to best angular practises.

```
// usage: <enclose disabled="someScopeVariable"></enclose>
.directive('enclose', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      value: '=',
      // One time binding is only supported natively in 1.3+.
      maxLength: '::'
    },
    link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
      var maxLength = parseInt($scope.maxLength);
      // What purpose does $scope.$last serve here?
      if(!$scope.$last) return;
      $scope.$watch('value', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue === oldValue) {
          return;
        }

        if(oldValue.length > maxLength) {
          $elem.removeAttribute('disabled');
        } else {
          $elem.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
.controller('YourController', function($scope, attachmentService) {
  $scope.regulationGrid = {
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
      .....
      $scope.gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function() {
        $scope.currentPage = $scope.gridApi.pagination.getPage();
        // $http call is moved to external service.
        attachmentService.get($scope.row.entity.id)
          .then(function(data) {
            $scope.enclosedData = data;
          });
      });
    }
  };

})
.service('attachmentService', function() {
  this.get = function get(rowId) {
    // Why are you using getCurrentPath, by the way? That seems very hacky.
    // An alternative would be to use /api and then use a http interceptor to
    // rewrite /api to wherever the base path actually is. Either way,
    // the service shouldn't do this because of code duplication.
    return $http.get('/api/' + rowId + '/attachment').then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  };
});
```

Then your html MIGHT look like this:

```
<div ng-controller='YourController'>
  <enclose value="enclosedData" max-length="30">
  </enclose>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I expose you my goal: I have a list of some things who can have files attached. The way to know it is calling to Rest-service, if response length is over 30 (I dunno why 30, is what server responses) there is something attached. Once you know if there is, or no, file enclosed, I want to enable download button if it has, or disable, if it has no files.

Comment: Then I think you should use an approach similar to what I have suggested, but alter it as required to fit your needs.

Comment: Yep, I'm giving it a shot, I'll feed you back then. Thx, Dan!

Comment: No luck, the problem of your way is to call `$scope.row.entity.id` in the controller, 'cause it cannot know which rows are being displayed. This is the scenario: a table with 20 rows, paging 5 rows each. Controller knows there are 20 rows, directive see only 5. It works for this 5 initial rows, but doesn't for the following. :(